# Java method return type, predefined Collection vs Collector?

Tags: java, java-8

I just have a question regarding code reusability in method return type.

In Java 8 there is the concept of collectors where the user will specify the type of collection the stream would return.

would it be beneficial if base retrieval methods accept the Collector parameter instead of returning a predefined Collection, say list.

the method with the predefined Collection will then pass the Collectors.toList() to the base retrieve method.

Comment: In some cases, yes.  In other no.  What are you really asking here?  (And what do you mean by a "static collection"?  Do you mean an object with specific implementation class?  A reference to an object that is shared via a `static`?)

Comment: Hi @Stephen C, I changed the static to predefined, what I mean is instead of declaring the method will return List, the type will depend on the Collector passed :)

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  What do you consider to be a "base retrieval method"?

Comment: Take `Stream` for example. The collect method there takes a custom `Collector` object to retrieve values. That's because there needs to be customization for that API to be re-used by so many different code-bases. In most cases, I'd say returning a list is probably enough; but that really depends on the scope. So what is the scope of your project? Who needs to call the code? Does it need to be that flexible?

Comment: The answer is still "in some cases yes, in others now".  Your question is Too Broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `java.util.stream.Stream` provides the functionality that you describe, there's little reason for any other class to do the same: instead of taking a `Collector`, collecting a stream into it, and returning the result, it makes much more sense to just return the stream to begin with: it's clearer, and it gives the caller much more flexibility than just the choice of collection type.

That said, in most cases you're better off just returning an appropriate collection type. You usually have a better sense than your clients of what collection-types make sense for a given API, and your clients don't usually care that much unless there's some reason that they would want to mutate the collection afterward. If you just return a `Stream`, you're giving your clients less information about what to expect (unless you then compensate for it by putting the information in the Javadoc, that they then have to read and make sense of).

Comment: I guess I should have thought about it thoroughly before asking this question. It is a case to case basis.